Using Python to get a solution to a system of linear equations with as many zeros as possible in the solution
I'm trying to solve a linear system of equations in Python with a very sparse, relatively big matrix (size around 10 x 10000). Using Numpy, it was easy to get a numerical solution using the least squares method. However, it has next to no zeros in it, meaning the result is a linear combination of thousands of vectors.
I also tried using SymPy, so that I could try to tinker with the parameters to maximize the number of zeros, but I don't know it well at all, and am not sure if there's a way to do it with so many variables at once.
Basically, my question then is: is there a way to either (1) specify to Numpy that I want as many zeros as possible in the solution (instead of the usual norm minimization); or (2) solve big systems directly in SymPy?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Is this supposed to be an overdetermined system, or an underdetermined one? It sounds like it's supposed to be underdetermined, but I just want to make sure.

Trying to maximize the number of zeros is awkward, because "number of zeros" is a discontinuous objective function. IIRC, this kind of thing has serious numerical stability issues.

@user2357112 Your assumption is correct - extremely underdetermined, in principle.

@user2357112 My problem is that the system is big to the point in which I’m not even sure if there’s a solution of the form (0,0,…,0,1,0,…,0) - I don’t think there is, but there could be similarly simple solutions… Worst of all, all the coefficients of the answer are tiny (at most 10^-3), so I can’t even truncate it…

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Do you expect there to be an exact solution or are you looking for least squares? Can you give an example? My initial thought is to find r linearly independent columns, where r is the rank of the matrix) and then set all variables that don't correspond to those columns to 0.

While it doesn't directly optimize for having many zeros, Lasso regression has the effect of making many coefficients zero by adding an L1 penalty to the coefficients.

It sounds like this is an instance of problem type commonly referred to as "compressed sensing". There is a tutorial for solving such problems with scipy.optimize.milp: https://nbviewer.org/github/scipy/scipy-cookbook/blob/main/ipython/LinearAndMixedIntegerLinearProgramming/compressed_sensing_milp_tutorial_2.ipynb. if that is too slow, take a look at https://nbviewer.org/github/scipy/scipy-cookbook/blob/main/ipython/LinearAndMixedIntegerLinearProgramming/compressed_sensing_milp_tutorial_1.ipynb. You might also find special libraries for it.

@jared My hope is that there is an exact solution, though I’m not positive it exists…

It is difficult to answer the question without seeing the system itself. I suggest showing some code that makes something similar to your actual problem.

This can be thought of as an assignment problem where every element of the solution matrix is either assigned (non-zero) or unassigned (zero). At this scale, a sparse matrix of 1% density and dimensions m=10, n=10_000 can quickly converge on a solution that has p*m non-zeros.
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint


def fake_data(
    rand: np.random.Generator,
    m: int, n: int, p: int,
    density: float = 0.1,
) -> tuple[sp.csc_array, np.ndarray]:
    A = sp.lil_array((m, n))
    n_A = int(density * m * n)
    A[
        rand.integers(low=0, high=m, size=n_A),
        rand.integers(low=0, high=n, size=n_A),
    ] = rand.uniform(low=-1e-3, high=1e-3, size=n_A)

    x_ideal = rand.uniform(low=-1e-3, high=1e-3, size=(n, p))

    b = A @ x_ideal
    return A.tocsc(), b


def solve(
    A: sp.csc_array,
    b: np.ndarray,
    density_objective: bool = False,
) -> np.ndarray:
    m, n = A.shape
    m, p = b.shape

    # Variables: x (p*n), continuous linear solution; a (p*n), binary assignments
    b_flat = b.T.ravel()
    product_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.hstack((
            sp.kron(A=sp.eye_array(p), B=A),
            sp.csc_array((m*p, n*p)),
        ), format='csc'),
        lb=b_flat, ub=b_flat,
    )

    # x <= a, -x <= a  -> -x + a >= 0, x + a >= 0
    assign_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.block_array([
            [-sp.eye(p*n), sp.eye(p*n)],
            [sp.eye(p*n), sp.eye(p*n)],
        ]),
        lb=0,
    )

    sparsity_constraint = LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.hstack((
            sp.csc_matrix((1, p*n)),
            np.ones((1, p*n)),
        )),
        ub=m*p,
    )

    result = milp(
        c=np.hstack((np.zeros(n*p), np.ones(n*p)))  # assignments (i.e. number of non-zeros) minimised
        if density_objective
        else np.zeros(2*p*n),  # nothing minimised
        integrality=np.hstack((
            np.zeros(n*p, dtype=np.uint8),   # x is continuous
            np.ones(n*p, dtype=np.uint8),    # assignments are binary
        )),
        bounds=Bounds(
            lb=np.hstack((
                np.full(p*n, fill_value=-np.inf),  # solution non-bounded
                np.zeros(p*n),                     # assignments binary
            )),
            ub=np.hstack((
                np.full(p*n, fill_value=np.inf),
                np.ones(p*n),
            )),
        ),
        constraints=(product_constraint, assign_constraint, sparsity_constraint),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    return result.x


def main() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    m = 10
    n = 10_000
    p = 2
    A, b = fake_data(rand, m=m, n=n, p=p, density=0.01)
    result = solve(A, b)

    x = result[:p*n].reshape((p, n)).T
    assign = result[p*n:].reshape((p, n)).T
    error = A@x - b
    n_nonzero = round(assign.sum(), 6)
    print('Nonzeros:', n_nonzero, '~', np.count_nonzero(np.round(x, 9)))
    print(f'Error: {error.min():.1e} - {error.max():.1e}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Nonzeros: 20.0 ~ 20
Error: -2.5e-19 - 9.3e-20

If it's even more sparse, the optimizer can improve upon that. For instance, a density of 1e-4 and density_objective=True reduces the number of non-zeros to 14.

I'm a bit unfamiliar with some of the code above, so sorry if it's a basic question: why did you take p = 2 if both b and x are supposed to be column vectors?

@Gauss I left it generic. Nowhere in the question did you say that those are strictly vectors. For your case set p=1.

Also, when running this code with my actual data, it throws an error stating that assign can't be reshaped, because it has way too much data to become a (1, 10) array...

The amount of data does not affect the ability to reshape; only the incoming shape affects this. If you wanted a sensible answer to accommodate your actual data, you should have included it (or at least a sample of it) in the question. Otherwise, you're left with this guesswork. If you can't figure out how to reshape the incoming data to work with it you'll have to post a separate question.

So, as I said, I have a matrix A of size 10 x 10000 and I'm trying to solve Ax = b given b with x having as few zeros as possible. Your solution produces a result which is of size 20000, which is something I don't understand... Could you please elaborate a bit?

For p=1 only, result will be of size 20,000 because there are two variables in it: the solution x and its assignment variables. This is documented in the comments in solve().

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
